# How to call in a kernel level function in user space

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging, function

I've developed some helper functions in the kernel. They're called by other functions in the kernel. Currently, they make my custom kernel panic :(

For debugging, I made them as a passive code just sitting in kernel with no effect on kernel functionality. I'm wondering whether there is a way to call those functions in user space after building and running?

Comment: @Gilles This question currently has more than 1K views. I do not see how this can be off topic. It is related to system level understanding of unix/linux. Where should I move this question to?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot easily do that (calling kernel functions directly from user space). The canonical way to invoke kernel functions from a user application is to use [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

You could make some kernel module -providing some device- which, thru the interface of the device (i.e. `read`,`write`,`ioctl` on that device) is calling your kernel functions.

You might patch the kernel (but I don't recommend doing that) to add a new syscall calling your kernel functions.

You might want to run your patched kernel in an hypervisor or some VM

**You should consider using [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) with [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).** This is a Linux specific feature designed for communication between kernel and user-land.

You'll need to **read documentation for several weeks** to use that feature. See http://kernelnewbies.org/ and of course study the source code of the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/).

Read also a good [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

Comment: My "helper" functions don't directly talk with a device. As their names are obvious, they are a bunch of helper functions to improve the existing methods in kernel. I need to simple test them externally in user space. How `ioctl` would be helpful?

Comment: @remmargorp Basile's answer is correct. You cannot call a kernel function from user space, you need to go through one of the existing mechanisms. You'll need to write at least some glue code in the kernel, to provide a way to trigger the execution of the kernel code, and pass parameters and results around. Besides `ioctl` and a new syscall, possibilities include `/proc` and `/sys`. I think a trigger via `/sys` is the easiest to set up.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question - I think @BasileStarynkevitch is right that in general, this is not something you can easily/reliably do, though in theory at least, if your code is abstract enough (doesn't really on any kernel dependencies) then I suppose you could link it to a stub userspace process and test that way.

Having said that the kernel does offer something that might be useful for you - [UML (User Mode Linux)](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) (note at the time of writing, this page appears to be down due to sourceforge infra problems - hopefully it'll be back soon)

UML is a special Linux ARCH which builds the whole of the kernel as a userspace executable.  When this executable is run, it fires up as the kernel normally does, but is all contained within the space of one userspace process.  This means that you can hook GDB directly into the UML process as you would any other userspace process and debug as normal, without having to fiddle about with kernel debuggers.

You will need at least the following:

- The kernel source tree for whatever kernel flavour it is you are using.
- Build the kernel using `ARCH=um`.  This may or may not be easy with whatever kernel and config you have.  Detailed steps are on the sourceforge page, if that comes back.  Also [more info here](http://www.landley.net/code/UML.html).
- In order to fire up this kernel, you will also need a filesystem for it to boot into.  There are some [pre-built ones here](http://fs.devloop.org.uk/).  Note not all filesystems will work with all kernels, so you may have to judiciously pick and choose.
- I'm assuming your code is part of a kernel module.  If so, you'll also have to build this module using `ARCH=um` and insmod it once the UML kernel process is up and running.

Comment: @remmargorp Sure.  Hopefully it is a useful debugging technique for you.